# cakephp - Element input is missing required attribute alt in my form->end()

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp v2.39 and having this error in the validation at w3.org website, but have no idea how to solve it. cakephp allows to use an image in the $this->Form->end('search.gif') or just plain text $this->form->end('search')

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end('search.gif'); ?>
```

The error this code generate is that the alt attribute is missing.

```
Line 75, Column 479: Element input is missing required attribute alt.
…><input type="image" src="/img/search_go.gif" /></div></form></div>
```

How to 'inject' this alt="search" into the right place, as using $options, put it in the wrong place and generates 3 errors instead of the only one I have now.

Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the $options is putting it before, but the following code is perfect and validates.     Form->end( array( 'label' => 'search.gif', 'alt' => 'search' )); ?>

Comment: +1 for solving your own question. You can also define default attributes for your form elements when you **create** your form.